# Fitting Scipy Betaprime distribution function on a histogram

Tags: python, scipy, frequency-distribution

I have a histogram of 2782 rows of records. I would like to fit a Betaprime distribution function with these following parameters:

```
a = 1.95
b = 4.58
location = 2.28
scale = 411.99
```

However with the below code, my histogram graph shows a flat "blue" line (which is the Betaprime function:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

betaprime = stats.betaprime
a, b, loc, scale = 1.95, 4.58, 2.28, 411.99
size = 2782 
y = betaprime.rvs(a, b, loc, scale, size=size)

param = betaprime.fit(Q1['OrderValue'], floc=0)
pdf_fitted = betaprime.pdf(Q1['OrderValue'], *param)
plt.plot(Q1['OrderValue'], pdf_fitted, color='b')

plt.hist(y)
plt.show()
```

What could have gone wrong with this code ? Am I missing something?

[Histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv5cM.jpg)

Comment: plt.hist(y, normed=True) ?

Comment: What does it mean to *have a histogram and fit a distribution with given parameters*?

Comment: I'm assuming that since I was able to fit a betaprime distribution to my data (visualised as a histogram) (which yielded a set of parameters: a,b,loc,scale) then, I can use these 4 parameters to fit them on another similar dataset. Please correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: I would also like to add that the 4 parameters are to be used in conjunction with the betaprime library.

Comment: @Dinesh Fitting a distribution means to determine the parameters from data. You did that with one data set. You can fit the distribution to another data set but then you may get different parameters. Now I'm not sure how and to what purpose you want to use the parameters from one data set on another data set.

Comment: @kazemakase thanks.  Your point made sense. I did a mistake. At this point, I would like to know if betaprime and all the other 80 plus of the rest of SciPy distributions have the equivalent 4 parameters of (a, b, loc, scale)? Secondly, I am trying to apply betaprime distribution on the other dataset that I posted here.

Comment: @Dinesh Most distributions have `loc` and `scale` but not all have `a` and `b` - and the meaning of those differs from distribution to distribution. There are other parameters too; for example the bernoulli distribution takes `p` and `loc` but no `a`, `b`, or `scale`.

Comment: @kazemakase awesome. Thank you!

Comment: @user333700, many thanks for your answer. I have managed to fix my graph using your point.